# Created php page in wordpress - Error Page can not be reached

Tags: pages, errors, 404-error

I want to create a folder within wordpress site at root and add a php page abc.php with simple code like
`<?php   echo "Test php page."   ?>`
But when I try to run this page like this  http://mydomainname.com/Myfolder/abc.php
it gives error "This site can’t be reached"
Why it is not reading my php page. I did the same on my another domain and it is working fine.
Please help.

Comment: Can't be reached? That shouldn't happen: if that's the correct path to a file the exists on disk then the server should run it without any interference from WordPress, assuming you have a reasonably default server configuration. Check your server access logs and errors logs.

Comment: However, that's not the WordPress way. If you want to run specific PHP you should probably do it as a shortcode or on a page-specific template.

Comment: Page exists at its correct location. I will learn about shortchode and page specific template. I will also check logs. Is there any server config that can restrict a page to run this way?

Comment: is there any thing need to be done in .htaccess file?

Comment: It is actually a payment gateway I have to create a page for user to enter amount and then redirect to 3rd party payment page.

Comment: why would that require an independent PHP file though? A page template, hooks, etc there are lots of alternative options. Otherwise there's not enough information to answer this question, we don't know what kind of server you have or how it's configured, Nginx/Apache/IIS/Litespeed/etc

Comment: I have to redirect to 3rd part credit card acceptance page and after payment have to come back to main site. will it be done thru page template?

Comment: Do you mean to handle a form posted to you directly from the payment gateway? I think the way that WooCommerce does that - and I don't really like it, but it's a fairly common pattern you'll see in code snippets - is to just check for a POST with the correct form values on every page load. Then you can tell the payment gateway to just post to any URL on your site e.g. the homepage.

Comment: Or do you mean the page that the user is directed to after payment? Yes you can set this up as a specific page in your site and put the code in your template or a plugin or a theme, or you can do the same as above and just check for the query string parameters for that redirection on every page load and e.g. send the users to their order page, and if it is a post back then handle that and generate some extra text at the top of the page.

Comment: As usual it's probably worth looking at how existing systems do this, e.g. WooCommerce payment gateways, and stealing their ideas.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. Template page solved the issue. I want to mark this question as Answered but in comment section I did find any such option.